# Symfony2 routing rules from database

Tags: symfony

What should I do, if I want add routing rules from database.  Should I use https://github.com/symfony-cmf/ChainRoutingBundle or there is another simpler solution?

Comment: Ask just specific question and don't blame anyone if you don't know the right solution. ;) Regarding making a dynamic routes I would use listener for kernel.request event. [More info](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/internals.html#kernel-request-event)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Listen to `kernel.request` and use the `$request->getPathInfo()` to query the database for a route. If you find one, set the `_controller` attribute on the request.

```
$request->attributes->set('_controller', $row['controller']);
```

If you are running the master branch (Symfony 2.1) your listener will need to have a priority greater than 32 so it will run before the router.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing that could possibly work is to add a route to your default controller:

@Route("/page/{slug}", requirements={"slug" = ".+"})

Then in the action, look up {slug} from a database table.

See [@Route](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html) and [/'s in routes](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html).

Comment: thanks, but i need for adding router from database. i found sonataAdmin bundle with detaied info.