# Symfony 2.1 kernel.request event cannot override _controller

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-2.1

I'm trying to send some requests to a specific controller. I'm following Kris Wallsmith's answer here:

[Symfony2 routing rules from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799623/symfony2-routing-rules-from-database)

However when I override the request's _controller attribute my template is no longer decorated with the base template.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my listener service:

```php
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/RequestListener.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class RequestListener
{
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if (some logic) {
            $request = $event->getRequest();
            $request->attributes->set('_controller', 'Acme\DemoBundle\Controller\DefaultController::testAction');
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my template:

```
{# src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Default/test.html.twig #}
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Test{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {{ body | markdown }}
{% endblock body %}
```

Here's my controller:

```php
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

/**
 * @Route("/test")
 * @Template()
 */
public function testAction()
{
    return $this->render('AcmeHelloBundle:Default:test.html.twig', array('body' => 'test'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

don't know if it can help, but in 2.0 i use

```
$controller = $event->getController();
$event->setController(controller);
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice Chopchop but the `GetResponseEvent $event` has no `getController()` method.  When I try your suggestion I get the following error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent::getController()`

Answer (score 0):

You must use kernel.controller event. http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/internals.html#kernel-controller-event

Pass `FilterControllerEvent` as an argument to your listener method and use `setController, getController` methods of the event class.