# Symfony2 dynamically select controller based on query result

Tags: symfony, routes

I'm trying to create an extendible cms. I have URLs in my database like "/menu-item/content" for each of these urls there is an action specified in format "AcmeDemoBundle:Default:index".
I would like to resolve this action and call the appropriate controller based on the matched URL.

My main goal is to call the controller stored in the db directly. Before i used a method when i put a route in the end of the routings which matched all urls associate a controller with it that found out the target controller from the db, than used Controller::forward() to get the expected results. The main problem with this approach is that i need to create an unnecessary subrequest for each page load. The other problem is passing post variables to this new subrequest.

So far i've tried to listen on kernel.request event and modify $request->attributes to contain the matching _controller value, but it seems like it has no effect.

Any advice in the subject is appreciated.

Comment: According to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799623/symfony2-routing-rules-from-database, you need to set a higher priority than 32 to the listener. Did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mixed up the forward and redirect calls. [Redirect](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#redirecting) performs 301 or 302 redirects (permanent and temporary respectfully), which creates the subrequest, as you call it. [Forward](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#forwarding) performs internal call (same request) to the new action. As for your second problem, as forward is an internal call within the same request, everything global stays the same (including POST variables). In my opinion, using forward might be a good solution for you (if you don't have any other low-level requirements or if you want to be even more flexible than the usual MVC operation allows).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry you are wrong. Forward creates a subrequest. see: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#forwarding
Only GET variables preserved on forwarding, altough the superglobal $_POST remains untouched the Request object passed to the targeted action only contains the get variables.

Comment: Are we reading the same thing? 

_You can also easily forward to another controller internally with the forward() method. Instead of redirecting the user's browser, it makes an **internal sub-request**, and calls the specified controller. The forward() method returns the Response object that's returned from that controller:_ 

This means it's redirected on the server, not on the browser.

Comment: Yes, i was wrong about the post values. But making internal sub-request is unnecessary in my case. I want to avoid that.

Comment: Oh, in that case it becomes more complicated. Have you considered reimplementing your own matcher? You can override an existing one or implement an entirely new one. The more interesting part is to register it with the DI as a service, so that it gets injected in the Routing service properly. I guess it should be enough for you to change its class in the config to point to your own implementation. [Here is an example](https://github.com/symfony/Routing/blob/master/Matcher/UrlMatcher.php).

Comment: Ok, so it seems it's not being injected as a service, but there's a [config option](https://github.com/symfony/Routing/blob/master/Router.php#L104) which sets the Matcher class.

Comment: It looks intresting. I don't have time to check it right now. I'll check it soon and report back. Thank you!